# PureRenderMixin & state management design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins

I have some top-level component (`RegisrationPage`) with state, which pass it state/props to dump bottom-level components (`InputField`, `Dropdown`, `Datepicker`).
Bottom-level components change `RegistrationPage`'s state with help of callbacks.

***Problem:*** PureRenderMixin doesn't work since I have to bind state-change-callback that are passed to bottom-level components.

***Question:*** *how to make `PureRenderMixin` works in the most elegant way?*

Let's explain it with code:

***InputBlock:***

```
const React = require('react'),
      PureRenderMixin = require('react-addons-pure-render-mixin');

module.exports =  React.createClass({
    mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        input: React.PropTypes.string,
        onChange: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    render() {
        //PROBLEM - is re-rendered each time , since onChange callback each time is an different object due bind method call
    }

});
```

***RegistrationPage:***

```
RegistrationPage = React.createClass({  

    /**
     * Since all state is held by `RegistrationPage` and bottom-level components are dump,
     * I do _onFieldChange.bind - _onFieldChange should know which field should be changed
     */
    render() {
        return CreateFragment({
            email: <InputBlock
                input={this.state.email}
                onChange={this._onFieldChange.bind(self, 'email')}/>,
            firstName: <InputBlock
                input={this.state.firstName}
                onChange={this._onFieldChange.bind(self, 'firstName')}/>,
            .........
        });
    },

    _onFieldChange(key, event) {
        //Save registered progress to store and re-render the component
        AppActionCreators.saveRegisterProgress(this.state);
    }
})
```

---

My workaround: just pass `inputFieldName` as extra property and do binding inside bottom-level component.

Comment: have you considered using a flux-store? I'd rather store the values within onChange into a flux-store instead of using the callback-based approach

Comment: @DERIIIFranz please explain what do you mean

Comment: have a look at: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Comment: alternativly use [Immstruct](https://github.com/omniscientjs/immstruct) in combination with [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: @DERIIIFranz I haven't such many data to justify  persistent data structure like Immutable.js. What about facebook flux? I've read that all. May you provide an example please?

Comment: @DERIIIFranz looks more like you haven't read my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.bind()` returns a new function every time you invokes it. To avoid it, you should create functions outside rendering. For example:

```
    RegistrationPage = React.createClass({  
        render() {
            return CreateFragment({
                email: <InputBlock
                    input={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this._onEmailChange}/>,
                firstName: <InputBlock
                    input={this.state.firstName}
                    onChange={this._onFirstNameChange}/>,
                .........
            });
        },

        _onFieldChange(key, event) {
            //Save registered progress to store and re-render the component
            AppActionCreators.saveRegisterProgress(this.state);
        }

        _onEmailChange() {
            this._onFieldChange('email')
        }

        _onFirstNameChange() {
            this._onFieldChange('firstName')
        }
    })
```